# GNOME Settings Won't Launch in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, settings, gnome-control-center

I'm configuring a relatively new installation of Disco & something happened that caused the GNOME Settings app to not be able to launch.

Do I need to reinstall a package? If so, which one? I'd think it would be `gnome-control-center`, but doing that seems to have no effect.

Running this command from the terminal produces literally no output; clicking the settings launcher icon brings up a loading cursor for a few seconds and nothing else.

edit: here's the requested output of `journalctl`:

```
Aug 10 21:31:26 xps-ubuntu dbus-daemon[858]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.175' (uid=1000 pid=2855 comm="gnome-control-center " label="unconfined")
Aug 10 21:31:27 xps-ubuntu gnome-control-center.desktop[1341]: nvc0_screen_create:1007 - Error allocating PGRAPH context for M2MF: -16
Aug 10 21:32:13 xps-ubuntu gnome-control-center.desktop[1341]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
Aug 10 21:32:51 xps-ubuntu gnome-software[2408]: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop file: cannot process file of type application/x-desktop
Aug 10 21:33:25 xps-ubuntu gnome-control-center.desktop[1341]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
Aug 10 21:46:33 xps-ubuntu gnome-control-center.desktop[1341]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
Aug 10 21:46:49 xps-ubuntu gnome-control-center.desktop[1341]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
Aug 10 22:09:40 xps-ubuntu gnome-control-center.desktop[1341]: Failed to register: Timeout was reached
Aug 10 22:12:43 xps-ubuntu sudo[12873]:    sigma : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/sigma ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
Aug 10 22:12:45 xps-ubuntu gnome-software[2408]: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop file: cannot process file of type application/x-desktop
```

Comment: Please try `killall gnome-control-center; gnome-control-center -vvv` -- if no sucess edit your question with the output of `journalctl -b | grep gnome-control-center`

Comment: I've updated the question with the results of the latter.

Comment: try to set `nomodeset` to `default.grub` explained here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132